# Allegro 5 al_draw_textf()

Tags: c++, allegro5

I have been looking how to draw string on the screen using Allergo 5 and knew about `al_draw-textf()` which was said to work like printf() in stdio.h . So when I want to print a string on console window I write `printf("%s" , string_name);` But when I write this

> al_draw_textf(font , al_map_rgb(255 , 255 , 0) , 250 , 250 ,
>   ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT  , "%s" , num);

there is nothing written on the display . When I change the `%s` to `%d` and the num variable to an integer it draws the value of the num correctly . Am I doing something not correctly or this function is only used to draw integer variables ?

Comment: Can you show a relevant example of your code?

Comment: I have already fixed this problem . I should have declared the `num` variable as a `const char *` instead of string

Comment: @Sam379, you can use the `c_str()` method if you are using C++ strings to pass a C compatible string to Allegro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is draw a constant string without formatting, just use:

```
void al_draw_text(const ALLEGRO_FONT *font,
   ALLEGRO_COLOR color, float x, float y, int flags,
   char const *text)
```

Although what you are doing should still work, so if the above doesn't help, you'll need to post more code.